# Http Module to change culture has no effect

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo

I am using `CultureModule.cs` in my project to set culture info based on the value of my variable. Here is the example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Globalization; 

namespace CwizBankApp
{
    public class CultureModule:IHttpModule 
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PostAuthenticateRequest += 
                          new EventHandler(context_PostAuthenticateRequest);
        }
        void context_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CultureInfo currentCulture;
            if (Global.gDateFormat.Trim() == "British")
            {
                currentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
            }
            else
            {
                currentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            }


            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture 
                                                             = currentCulture;
        }
    }
}
```

After this I am configuring it in web.config as follows:

```
<add name="CultureModule" 
               type="CwizBankApp.HttpModules.CultureModule,CwizBankApp"/>
```

Currently my variable is in British format, however dates are being performed in US format.

My question is, am I doing it in a right manner or something is still missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formats depend on [Thread.CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx).

So you would do:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
```

See [how to set the Culture in asp.net on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: ,,,, i tried doing that but the date that i am trying to compare are still being compared in US format ,,, i am using compare validator to comapre them

Comment: <asp:CompareValidator ID="idissuedate1" runat="server" Text="X" ErrorMessage="Personal Information - Identification Issue Date Cannot Be Greater Than Identification Expiry Date" Operator="LessThan" ControlToValidate="txtIDIssueDate" ControlToCompare="txtIDExpiryDate"  Type=Date></asp:CompareValidator>

Comment: @freebird I hope you noticed the code says Current**UI**Culture. Can you describe better what is going wrong? It is **displaying** in the wrong format? Or is actual comparison not working.

Comment: ,,,, based on my httpmodule ,,, culture is either set to en-GB or en_US ,,, they are set based on the value of Global.gDateFormat ...

Comment: ok, but what is not working? Is the date displaying wrong or the comparison doesn't work **when you enter the date in the correct format**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8621/discussion-between-gideon-and-freebird)

Comment: ,, comparison is the problem ,,, suppose i enter two dates 01/02/2011 and 11/01/2011 ,,, it would not give error although the first date is greater...